# SQL Server : indexing for table and columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where I am storing all tables name and column name, now I want to get data according to that table with different conditions.

I will use one single query column name and table name will take dynamically from this table and than I will use in select query and will get data from respective column and table.

Table name is `ADE_ColumnIndexing`

In this table I have all table names as `TableName` column, and column names as `name` column...

Now I want to use

```
select fieldname 
from tablename 
where Id = newdata
```

This query will return data of that column and table... I mean `tablename = ade_log and columnname = history`...

So my query will be select history from ade_log... Is it possible?

Comment: for clarification .: I have 3 fields in a table : 1 is ColumnName, 2nd is TableName ,third is Idvalue ,now I will make a select query ,it will take select columnname from tablename where id = Idvalue,means,..tthat will give me output for selected tablename which is stored in this table...

Comment: I want the any table data through the system schema using sql query...

Comment: Seems like bad design to me.

Comment: yes Zohar,see only this comment : is it possible I want the any table data through the system schema using sql query...

Comment: how are you choosing what row to take from this table?

Comment: you can think I have table,where I have 3 columns.1 is columnname,2. is tablename,3rd name is IDval. now in this I have 5 fields,i will choose acc. to IDval...like as 1 row have FirstName,Customer,1,..than my query will return select Firstname from Customer where IDval=1

Comment: why not select directly from the table? why do you want to build dynamic sql?

Comment: I need this type of things.if you are able to do ,than please tell me,simply I want only that things.i have 3 columns in a table ,1 is column name ,2 is table name ,3 is ID value, I want a query with 4rth column,where I will get the data acc. to given columnname,tablename and ID value

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to build and execute dynamic sql, though it doesn't seem like a good aproach:

```
DECLARE @Sql varchar(max)

SELECT @Sql = 'SELECT '+ ColumnName +
              ' FROM '+ TableName +
              ' WHERE Id = '+ IdValue
FROM ADE_ColumnIndexing
WHERE TableName = @TableName
AND ColumnName = @ColumnName

EXEC(@Sql)
```

Comment: I am getting this error : The multi-part identifier "ci.ColumnName" could not be bound.

Comment: use `print @sql` instead of `exec(@sql)` copy the sql statement and paste in a comment. I have no `ci` identifier in my answer, so I don't understand where you get that from.

Comment: I have a ID column and queries column in a table,in Queries column I have multiple rows with select queries,now can I get output with ID,Queries and output column of this queries column ?

Comment: Now I'm completely lost. I don't understand how is that relevant to what I've asked you to do. Please consider editing your question so that it will reflect your database clearly.

Comment: This is my new query , I am doing that things by other way , I have a ID column and queries column in a table,in Queries column I have multiple rows with select queries,now can I get output with ID,Queries and output column of this queries column ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I give up. we don't seem to speak the same language

Comment: your query was giving error,so I made new changes. and change logic. so now there are multiple query in a column of a table ,now I want output of all queries in second alias column name ,is it possible ?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect your current table structure.

Comment: my table structure is : queries
 select ClosureComment from EM_Note where Id= 3
 select ClosureComment from EM_Note where Id= 15
 select Progress from EM_Update where Id= 4
 select Progress from EM_Update where Id= 7
 select PSR_BriefProblemDescription from EM_Note where Id= 16  now I want to execute all queries and show output column with this column

Comment: simply I am saying again and again that I have a table with two columns.one column is ID ,and 2nd column is multiple select queries,now I want to show ID ,queries column and output of 2nd column queries in 3rd column,is it possible?? this is my exact and final query,so please  give me reply acc. to this question ,leave all questions..hope that now you have got my question

Comment: You are going to have to make it clearer, perhaps with more diagrams. My general advice is: whatever you are trying to do it sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: no my friend, I am trying to make a simple and easy way to run multiple queries,and  I have simple query that I have a column in a table,this column have multiple select queries in multiple rows,now I want to execute this table with that column columnname.means  like select queriescolumn ,outputcolumn from tablenam ,simple,i want this things.i am not understanding that what you want to say.and why r u not understanding ? this things is not a bad idea,this is very creative idea.ok,if you have solution than ping me else don't try .its challenging,if you can't accept this challenge,than don't do

Comment: Again, Please edit your question to reflect your current table structure. It's very hard to read code posted in comments.

Comment: you can take your own query friend,just create a table in ur local db ,and create two column in this table, one is Id ,2nd is Queries,insert 5 rows,in Queries column insert select query in every row for any other tables, now try to get result Id,Queries,and output of these queries,simply,why r u being confused again and again,

Comment: You are asking too much. I have no intention of doing such a thing. If you can't show your table structure and sample data I sure as hell am not going to do the dirty work for you.

Comment: I am asking only simple query again and again I don't know what's problem with you ,now see that :                                                                                                             queries
 select ClosureComment from EM_Note where Id= 3
 select ClosureCriteria from EM_Note where Id= 3
 select ExpectedResult from EM_Note where Id= 3
 select SpecialInstructions from EM_Note where Id= 3
                   this is my table structure data,now I need another column with given select queries..

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use the ID column for search, definitely not recommended as it may seem to me, the IDVal is auto-increment (correct me if i'm wrong). So why not use

```
exec('select [' + @column_name + '] from [' + @tablename + ']');
```

if you want an added validation if the table or column exists, you may query in sys.

```
if (
    select
        COUNT(*)
    from sys.tables tb
    left join sys.columns c
    on
        tb.object_id = c.object_id
    where
        tb.name = @tablename
        and c.name = @columnname
  ) != 0
    begin
        exec('select [' + @column_name + '] from [' + @tablename + ']');
    end
  else
    begin
        select 'table or column does not exist'
    end
```

EDIT : Seems like your table has "queries" as a row, then see my simple script below if I understand you correctly....(hopefully)

```
CREATE TABLE test (qry nvarchar(4000)) -- test query table
    CREATE TABLE test1 (sales decimal(18,2)) -- sales table

    INSERT INTO test1 (sales) -- dummy records for sales table
    values (5923.59), (5923.52),(5923.51)

    INSERT INTO test (qry) -- dummy records for query table
    values ('select * from test1 where sales = 5923.59')
    ,('select * from test1 where sales = 5923.52')
    ,('select * from test1 where sales = 5923.51')

    declare @myqry nvarchar(4000) = (SELECT qry + '; ' AS [text()] FROM test FOR XML PATH('')) -- from records to 1 query statement with multiple table results
    declare @myqry2 nvarchar(4000) = SUBSTRING(
                                        (SELECT qry + ' union all ' AS [text()] FROM test FOR XML PATH(''))
                                        ,0
                                        ,LEN((SELECT qry + ' union all ' AS [text()] FROM test FOR XML PATH(''))) - 9
                                    )
                                         -- from records to 1 query statement with single table results
    select 'my query', @myqry -- see content of @myqry
    select 'my query 2', @myqry2 -- see content of @myqry2
    EXEC(@myqry) -- execute @myqry
    EXEC(@myqry2) -- execute @myqry2
```

EDIT : This is my last attempt for your case. Please try this sample code set which still uses table:[test] and table:[test1]

```
DECLARE @intloop INT = 1 -- variable setter for number of loops
    ,@qry nvarchar(4000) = '' -- variable setter for the looping query

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY qry) AS id, qry INTO #tmpQueries FROM [test] -- create temp table for fake 'id'
CREATE TABLE #tmpQuery (id int, qry nvarchar(4000), res nvarchar(4000)) -- table result container
CREATE TABLE #tmpInsert (res nvarchar(4000)) -- execute query container

WHILE (@intloop < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmpQueries) + 1)
BEGIN

    SET @qry = (SELECT TOP 1 qry FROM #tmpQueries WHERE id = @intloop) -- get the qry base from ID

    DELETE FROM #tmpInsert -- delete records of query container
    INSERT INTO #tmpInsert -- insert records into query container
    EXEC (@qry) -- execute qry

    INSERT INTO #tmpQuery (id, qry, res)
        VALUES (@intloop, @qry, (SELECT TOP 1 res FROM #tmpInsert)) -- transfer id, qry and result into #tmpQuery table

    SET @intloop = @intloop + 1 -- increment record

END

SELECT * FROM #tmpQuery -- select all records in #tmpQuery table
DROP TABLE #tmpQueries
DROP TABLE #tmpQuery
DROP TABLE #tmpInsert
```

NEW TABLE SAMPLE STRUCT : Create identity ID's for test and test1, and specify ID inside query. (notice the `select * from test1` before into `select id, sales from test1`)

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int identity(1,1), qry nvarchar(4000)) -- test query table
CREATE TABLE test1 (id int identity(1,1), sales decimal(18,2)) -- sales table

INSERT INTO test1 (sales) -- dummy records for sales table
values (5923.59), (5923.52),(5923.51)

INSERT INTO test (qry) -- dummy records for query table
values 
('select id, sales from test1 where sales = 5923.59')
,('select id, sales from test1 where sales = 5923.52')
,('select id, sales from test1 where sales = 5923.51')
```

SIMPLIFIED SCRIPT : Assuming all ID's of test and test1 are siblings, you can simply do the query this way.

```
declare @myqry2 nvarchar(4000) = SUBSTRING(
                                        (SELECT qry + ' union all ' AS [text()] FROM test FOR XML PATH(''))
                                        ,0
                                        ,LEN((SELECT qry + ' union all ' AS [text()] FROM test FOR XML PATH(''))) - 9
                                    )
CREATE TABLE #tmpResult(id int, qry nvarchar(4000))
INSERT INTO #tmpResult
EXEC(@myqry2) -- execute @myqry2

SELECT 
    tr.id
    , t.qry
    , tr.qry AS [sales]
FROM [test] t
LEFT JOIN #tmpResult tr
ON
    t.id = tr.id

DROP TABLE #tmpResult
```

EDIT : We can remove the substring, but as per your request, all rows must be in single table result, so "union all" can't be un-done, unless you have your own ways, that's a plus.

```
select 
    *, 
    case 
        when id = 1 then ' union all ' 
        when id = 2 then ' union all '
        else ''
    end as [row_extender]
into #tmptest
from test
--drop table #tmptest

declare @myqry2 nvarchar(4000) = (SELECT qry + row_extender AS [text()] FROM #tmptest FOR XML PATH(''))
CREATE TABLE #tmpResult(id int, qry nvarchar(4000))
INSERT INTO #tmpResult
EXEC(@myqry2) -- execute @myqry2

SELECT 
    tr.id
    , t.qry
    , tr.qry AS [sales]
FROM [test] t
LEFT JOIN #tmpResult tr
ON
    t.id = tr.id

DROP TABLE #tmpResult
DROP TABLE #tmptest
```

Comment: my case is :Queries(column name of a table)
select ClosureComment from EM_Note where Id= 3
select ClosureComment from EM_Note where Id= 15
select Progress from EM_Update where Id= 4
select Progress from EM_Update where Id= 7           now I want output of all queries in second alias column name using one shot sql query

Comment: may I ask, why are you querying in ID? is that ID column hardcoded and not auto increment?

Comment: my friend ,Queries is column name and all select queries are row of this column,so what is the issue with Id ,,I want only on thing that is new column where I want output of all these rows parallel simply..ok

Comment: hi good sir, kindly see my edit, hopefully I understood you correctly this time..

Comment: not gud sir,i am not understanding that why r u not understanding my query ,I am simply saying that I have a table,there are two column ,1st is ID ,2nd is Queries,in second column there are 5 rows,every row have new select query,now I want to see output of this column as a 3rd column,how can I find out,

Comment: have you tried executing my sample script after EDIT?

Comment: yes,you can just copy paste ,it will generate for tables..what's this,i want all things in same table parallely

Comment: you can change the "; " into " union all " if you want it in same table.

Comment: i've added something for @myqry2, please check again. thanks

Comment: brother,please check it acc. to my requirement,i am not understanding that what you are running,i want 3 columns in result in same table, 1 is Id,2nd is queries, 3 rd is output of 2nd column queries parallely ,please make query acc. to this,thanks

Comment: brother,please check it acc. to my requirement,i am not understanding that what you are running,i want 3 columns in result in same table, 1 is Id,2nd is queries, 3 rd is output of 2nd column queries parallely ,please make query acc. to this,thanks,for more into :CREATE TABLE test (qry nvarchar(4000),Id int) -- test query table
   
    INSERT INTO test (qry,Id) -- dummy records for query table
    values ('select Id from test where Id = 1',1)
    ,('select Id from test where Id = 2',2)
    ,('select Id from test where Id = 3',3)
 select * from test,3rd column will come by qry

Comment: I've added my final edit, please see that code script for your use. thanks

Comment: yes brother, now you have got my point ,what I was saying ,this is right,but this is too much big.there can be a simpl solution of this query.because we are using 3 temp table in single query,this is not gud ,if I use in big Stored procedure,so it will not be reliable..so try to merge in one single temp table,if you can

Comment: i'd expect you'd say that because EXEC(string) is not a built-in function which means the result of EXEC(string) cannot be direct to a column. I've added an edit, please drop your existing table [test] and [test1] and re-create using the "new table sample struct" i've added, then execute the "simplified script" i've also included.

Comment: can we do that things without using substring and union all,because right now you are using only one table,but if you have multiple join and you need to create multiple select query acc. to table,than it can create problem,so there is any way without substring and union all

Comment: my bad but that's the best of my knowledge so far. Using SQL queries from a table row is actually a bad practice simply because row columns have limits (and its IN memory, can you imagine the data lengths?) and even if unlimited, still not a good execution module compare with clean maintained stored procedures.

Comment: I've added an edit with I think answers your inquiry, using a custom column 'row_extender'. I do away with substring and you can modify the 'union all' with whatever a-joining row script you'd like to incorporate. However I can't go any further than this, sorry.